# Why is CUDA crashing upon accessing member of class?

Tags: c++, oop, cuda

Sorry if this is a new problem, but I could not find it. I have been coding a program that could use CDUA acceleration. However, my approach would rely heavily on passing of class objects (ENTIRELY, not just their members) to kernels to function. To determine if this is possible, I wrote a small test program.

```
class bulkArray {
public:
    double* value;
    int xSize;

    bulkArray(int xSize) {
        value = new double[xSize];
        this->xSize = xSize;
    }
};

__global__ void addArrays(bulkArray *a, bulkArray *b, bulkArray *c, int N) {
    int id = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

    if (id < N)
        c->value[id] = a->value[id] + b->value[id];
}

int main() {
    int N = 50000000;

    bulkArray *a;
    bulkArray *b;
    bulkArray *c;

    a = new bulkArray(N);
    b = new bulkArray(N);
    c = new bulkArray(N);

    // allocate unified memory.
    cudaMallocManaged(&a, sizeof(a));
    cudaMallocManaged(&b, sizeof(b));
    cudaMallocManaged(&c, sizeof(c));

    // init vectors on host.
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        // CRASHING HERE.
        a->value[i] = sin(i) * cos(i);
        b->value[i] = sin(i) * cos(i);
    }

    int blockSize = 1024;
    int gridSize = (int)ceil((float)N / blockSize);

    addArrays << <gridSize, blockSize >> > (a, b, c, N);

    // sum up vector c.
    double sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        sum += c->value[i];
    }

    cout << "Final result: " << sum << endl;

    cudaFree(a);
    cudaFree(b);
    cudaFree(c);

    return 0;
}
```

Somehow, loading the 3 objects into unified memory works, but fails when I attempt to access them for modification. I have looked to other guides and examples, and cannot quite identify what is going wrong. I apologize for the amount of code posted, but I couldn't help but worry that what I am attempting is not possible.

Comment: you shouldn't use `cudaMallocManaged` on a pointer already allocated with `new` (e.g. `a`).  Furthermore, the size of a pointer is always the size of a pointer, regardless of what you do with that pointer, so your use of `sizeof(a)` is not giving you what you expect, which is the proximal reason for the seg fault.  The sizeof a  pointer is a basic C programming issue, so you may want to study that.  Regarding `cudaMallocManaged`, you might want to study basic usage [here](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/even-easier-introduction-cuda/).

Comment: What @RobertCrovella said, in ctor of bulkarray, you should do `cudaMallocManaged(&value, xSize*sizeof(double));` in dtor you should do `cudaFree(value)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may have some misconceptions about how managed memory, or `cudaMallocManaged` works.  In some respects, `cudaMallocManaged` is conceptually like the C-library `malloc`, except that it allocates managed memory.  For a more detailed introduction to the use of managed memory in a simple CUDA application, you may want to refer to [this blog](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/even-easier-introduction-cuda/).

Specifically, here are some issues with your code:

1. When using a managed allocation for an array of objects that have embedded pointers, all levels of allocation need to be replaced with a managed allocation, if you intend to use that on the device.  Therefore, using `new` in the constructor won't work, if you want to access that member/field in device code.  We can substitute `cudaMallocManaged` there.
2. We don't allocate a pointer using `new` then re-allocate the same pointer with `cudaMallocManaged`.
3. The `sizeof` function in C (or C++) when used on a pointer will return the size of that *pointer*, not the size of whatever it points to.  So this isn't a sensible way to allocate for an array of objects.
4. CUDA kernel launches are asynchronous, so after a kernel launch, if you want to use managed data, it will be necessary to create some kind of synchronization.

What follows is a minimal set of modifications to address the above issues.  I've omitted proper CUDA error checking but I strongly recommend that when developing CUDA codes.  Also I recommend running this code with `cuda-memcheck` if you have difficulty with it:

```
$ cat t51.cu
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class bulkArray {
public:
    double* value;
    int xSize;

    void init(int xSize) {
        cudaMallocManaged(&value, xSize*sizeof(double));
        this->xSize = xSize;
    }
};

__global__ void addArrays(bulkArray *a, bulkArray *b, bulkArray *c, int N) {
    int id = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

    if (id < N)
        c->value[id] = a->value[id] + b->value[id];
}

int main() {
    int N = 50000;

    bulkArray *a;
    bulkArray *b;
    bulkArray *c;

    // allocate unified memory.
    cudaMallocManaged(&a, sizeof(bulkArray));
    cudaMallocManaged(&b, sizeof(bulkArray));
    cudaMallocManaged(&c, sizeof(bulkArray));
    a->init(N);
    b->init(N);
    c->init(N);
    // init vectors on host.
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        a->value[i] = sin(i) * cos(i);
        b->value[i] = sin(i) * cos(i);
    }

    int blockSize = 1024;
    int gridSize = (int)ceil((float)N / blockSize);

    addArrays << <gridSize, blockSize >> > (a, b, c, N);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    // sum up vector c.
    double sum = 0;
    double sum2 = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        sum += c->value[i];
        sum2 += a->value[i] + b->value[i];
    }

    cout << "Final result: " << sum << " should be: " << sum2 <<  endl;

    cudaFree(a);
    cudaFree(b);
    cudaFree(c);

    return 0;
}
$ nvcc -arch=sm_35 -o t51 t51.cu
$ cuda-memcheck ./t51
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
Final result: 0.624013 should be: 0.624013
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
$
```

Comment: allocations made with `cudaMalloc` are **only** accessible from CUDA device code.  An attempt to dereference a pointer created with `cudaMalloc` in host code will result in a seg fault. OTOH, using `cudaMallocManaged`, the resultant pointer can be safely dereferenced in either host code or device code. Since the above code dererences the `a` and `b` pointers in both host code and device code, `cudaMalloc`, by itself, will not work.  You're not going to learn all this by reading an API manual. There are various blogs and an entire section of the cuda programming guide explaining managed memory.